# Where can I find type definitions for Promise

Tags: typescript, types, promise

I'm making a simple class (`Primrose`) that extends the global `Promise` to add `resolve` and `reject` methods

```
export class Primrose<Resolution> extends Promise<Resolution>{

  private _resolve: /* Type binding should be here */
  private _reject:  /* Type binding should be here */

  constructor() {
    super((_resolve, _reject) => {
      this._resolve = _resolve
      this._reject = _reject
    })
  }

  resolve(resolution: Resolution) {
    this._resolve(resolution)
  }

  reject(rejection) {
    this._reject(rejection)
  }

}
```

I want to give `_promise` and `_reject` the proper type bindings, however I don't know where those are. Where can I find them?

Comment: Do you want them to have the bindings of the executor (i.e. of the resolve and reject handlers in `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})` or of the static `Promise.resolve` and `Promise.reject` methods?

Comment: the bindings of the executor

Answer (score 1):

You should get typings  for Promise if you either

a) Install types for node: npm install --save-dev @types/node

Or

b) Or if a browser framework, add "dom" to your lib array inside your tsconfig: lib: ["dom", "es2015"...etc]